# Avoid coalesce() or case when in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to avoid case when or coalesce in where clause and below is the current situation

```
where col= coalesce(@var,col)
```

How can I write this condition so that I can avoid `colesce()` uses in where clause but at same time able to handle the null case

Comment: WHERE '@var'  is null or col = '@var'    (Quotes not need, just to get around @ as user name issue)

Comment: variable should have to check is null or value if variable is null then it will col else variable

Comment: @Sparky in that case in varibale is null then or condition will evaluate and nothing will come but i need all value when variable is null

Comment: What your coalesce code is saying is "if @var is null, basically force TRUE"   My code is saying if '@var is null', return TRUE for this SARG, other, compare the column with the var value.   Same thing

Comment: If the variable is NULL, the OR condition will not be evaluated.   Try it out

Comment: @Sparky ok let me try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218141/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-sparky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
WHERE col = COALESCE(@var,col)
```

says "if  @var is NULL, return TRUE (since col always equals col)"   A different approach is:

```
WHERE @var is NULL or col = @var
```

If @var is NULL, then the OR condition short-circuits (never needs to do the second part)  If @var is NOT NULL, then the second part gets executed.